# Update to 20.04 VSCode debugger "Attach by Process ID" do not see process

Tags: 20.04, visual-studio-code, debug

I updated Ubuntu to 20.04, after this VSCode debugger "Attach by Process ID" do not see processes run with nodejs. I tried reinstall other versions from Ubuntu Software, and also from website, but it did not helped, same stuff.

Have any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
add `"type": "pwa-node"` in debugger config, so its looks like this:

```
    {
        "name": "Attach by Process ID",
        "processId": "${command:PickProcess}",
        "request": "attach",
        "skipFiles": [
            "<node_internals>/**"
        ],
        "type": "pwa-node"
    }
```

in case getting error about wrong configuration for debugger need to enable `"debug.node.useV3": true` and `"debug.chrome.useV3": true` to your user settings, the easy way to install this extension JavaScript Debugger (Nightly) https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.js-debug-nightly

Im not sure does Ubuntu 20.04 effect it or not, may be its just coincidence.